# ¿Cómo son los métodos de una clase Python por defecto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trasteando con `Python`, me he dado de bruces con un error tipo `takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. Mi método, que está dentro de una clase, era de la forma

```
def add(x, y):
    return x +y
```

Acababa de leer la documentación básica sobre [clases](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class) y conocía la existencia de los modificadores `@classmethod` y `@staticmethod`, que la documentación dice que son básicamente ["azúcar sintáctico"](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator). También sé que `self` o `cls` no son palabras reservadas, así que no importa si mi primer parámetro se llama `self`, `cls` o `x`.

El error obtenido me da por pensar que por defecto, los métodos de una clase son considerados métodos de clase (y el primer argumento es considerado una referencia a la clase/instancia) y si los quiero estáticos tengo entonces que poner el modificador, pero no he encontrado nada que lo indique explícitamente en la documentación.

Puede parecer obvio, pero para mí ha sido bastante contraintuitivo que si declaro

```
def saludar() :
   print("hola")
```

dentro de una clase, la llamada dará error porque la función tiene 0 parámetros pero intentaremos pasar uno (implícito) con la llamada. ¿Puede alguien confirmar que los métodos son por defecto de clase, como si estuvieran anotados con `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Los métodos de una clase, por defecto, funcionan de la siguiente forma:

---

### Caso 1: Métodos de Instancia

Una clase sin `@classmethod` o `@staticmethod`. Como mencionas, `self` o `cls` no son palabras reservadas pero son las sugeridas para mantener un estándar en la Programación Orientada a Objetos en Python:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(cualquiercosa, nombre):
        cualquiercosa.nombre = nombre

    def hola(cualquiercosa):
        print('¡Hola, %s!' % cualquiercosa.nombre)
```

Efectivamente, todos los métodos de una clase necesitan tener la referencia a la instancia. Como puedes apreciar ni siquiera estoy usando `self`.

```
>>> c1 = Clase('Diego')
>>> c1.hola()
¡Hola, Diego!
```

Esto es equivalente, aunque un poco tonto, pero demuestra la forma en que un método es llamada usando una instancia de la clase:

```
>>> c1 = Clase('Diego')
>>> Clase.hola(c1)
¡Hola, Diego!
```

No es posible llamar el método sin una instancia de por medio a menos que uses `@classmethod` como veremos en el **Caso 2**:

```
>>> Clase.hola()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clases.py", line 11, in <module>
    Clase.hola()
TypeError: unbound method hola() must be called with Clase instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

---

### Caso 2: Métodos de Clase

Una clase con `@classmethod`. Al decorar un método con `@classmethod` lo que le estás diciendo a Python es: "Python, por si acaso quiero usar ese método sin tener una instancia así que no me vengas con tonterías de `self`". Y Python te responderá: "Ok, pero entonces dame una referencia a la clase". Nuevamente, no es necesario usar `cls`:

```
class Clase:
    @classmethod
    def hola(cualquiertonteria, nombre):
        print('¡Hola, %s!' % nombre)

>>> Clase.hola('Diego')
¡Hola, Diego!
```

Esta clase ni siquiera tiene constructor, es una clase sin sentido que solo te saluda pero la puedes llamar sin necesidad de tener una instancia de la clase. Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(cualquiercosa, nombre, rango='Cadete'):
        cualquiercosa.nombre = nombre
        cualquiercosa.rango = rango

    def hola(cualquiercosa):
        print('¡Hola, %s! Eres un %s' % (cualquiercosa.nombre, cualquiercosa.rango))

    @classmethod
    def desde_nombre(cualquiertonteria, nombre):
        return cualquiertonteria(nombre)
```

El método `desde_nombre` lo que hace realmente es retornar una instancia de la clase. En este caso no hay mucha ciencia pero es muy útil en casos complejos en los que los datos recibidos no concuerdan con los parámetros del constructor.

```
>>> c1 = Clase.desde_nombre('Diego')
>>> c1.hola()
¡Hola, Diego! Eres un Cadete
```

---

### Caso 3: Métodos Estáticos

Clase con `@staticmethod`. En resumen lo que le dices a Python es "Python, voy a crear un método sin instancia y sin clase asi que no me vengas con tonterías de `self` o `cls`". Y Python te responderá: "¿Sabes que eso lo puedes hacer sin necesidad de una clase, no?". Un método con `@staticmethod` es prácticamente una forma elegante de llamar una función desde una clase, ya que no recibe ni la instancia, ni la clase misma.

Personalmente lo he usado pocas veces pero se me vienen casos en los que este método podría estar estrechamente relacionada a los datos que manejas en la clase y quieres mantener todo en el mismo sitio. Es decir, en vez de crear una función "helper" en otro módulo, pues lo creas en la misma clase como algún tipo de validación:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(cualquiercosa, nombre):
        cualquiercosa.nombre = nombre

    def hola(cualquiercosa):
        print('¡Hola, %s!' % cualquiercosa.nombre)

    @staticmethod
    def mis_padres_estan_locos(nombre):
        estan_locos = False
        if nombre in ('Hitler', 'Kakaroto'):
            estan_locos = True
        return estan_locos

>>> Clase.mis_padres_estan_locos('Hitler')
True
>>> Clase.mis_padres_estan_locos('Diego')
False
>>> Clase.mis_padres_estan_locos('Kakaroto')
True
```

---

Esto es, en resumen, más o menos como funcionan las clases en Python.

Comment: Gracias, muy completo. Estaba tratando en entender la diferencia trasteando con el intérprete y me habría llevado la tira entender la diferencia entre las tres cuando la sintaxis es, en ocasiones, idéntica.

Comment: ¡Cuidado, `class` sí es una palabra reservada!

Comment: @Darkhogg claro, `class` lo es, pero la convención usada en los métodos de clase `cls` no lo es.

Comment: @CésarBustíos Ya, pero en tu respuesta dice literalmente: «self o class no son palabras reservadas», lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: @Darkhogg cierto! Fue un typo, lo corrijo. Gracias!

Comment: ¿`cls` y el nombre de la clase son equivalentes?

Answer (score 7):

Los métodos de una clase en Python son por defecto métodos de instancia, necesitan una referencia al objeto en cuestión.

Si miras en la Wikipedia [Método_(informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29), distingue entre *métodos de instancia* y *métodos de clase o estáticos*, en Python (al contrario que en otros lenguajes) los métodos de clase y los estáticos son dos cosas diferentes. Esto se debe a que las clases en sí también son objetos.

Un **método de instancia**, en Python, necesita una referencia explícita a la instancia, de ahí el error `takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. El *azúcar sintáctico* está en que el interprete se encarga de pasar la referencia a la instancia como el primer parámetro del método, por eso es necesario el `self` en la declaración del método pero no la referencia a la instancia a la hora de hacer la llamada al método de forma: `instancia.metodo()`.

Un **método de clase** es un método de instancia del objeto clase, en Python las clases son también objetos. Para indicar al intérprete que dicho método no va a pertener a las instancias de la clase sino al objeto clase en sí, es necesario el decorador [@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod). Como todo método de instancia necesita una referencia al objeto sobre el que se ejecuta, en este caso se utiliza `cls`. Tanto `self` como `cls` son palabras arbitrarias, pero la convención es usar dichas palabras, de acuerdo con la filosofía del [Zen de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) que dice que *solo debe haber una única manera obvia de hacer algo*. Se usan generalmente como *inicializadores* alternativos a `__init__`.

Por último, un **método estático** es una función (no necesita ningún objeto ni referencia a la clase para funcionar) pero necesita el decorador [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#staticmethod) para que el interprete no lo tome como un método de instancia.

---

Se ve mejor con código. Si definimos la clase `Clase` y una instancia:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    @staticmethod
    def metodo_estatico(arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

    def metodo_instancia(self, arg3):
        return self.arg1 + self.arg2 + arg3

    @classmethod
    def metodo_clase(cls, arg1):
        arg2 = 2
        return cls(arg1, arg2)

>>> instancia = Clase(4, 2)
```

`Clase` es un objeto de tipo type, `instancia` es un objeto de tipo `Clase`:

```
>>> Clase
<class '__main__.Clase'>
>>> type(Clase)
<class 'type'>
>>> instancia
<__main__.Clase object at 0x7f1354c17278>
>>> type(instancia)
<class '__main__.Clase'>
```

El `metodo_instancia` hasta que no pertenece a una instancia de la clase es una *función, 'function'* (En Python 2 sería un *'unbound method', método no enlazado*):

```
>>> Clase.metodo_instancia
<function Clase.metodo_instancia at 0x7f1354bf89d8>
```

Pero una vez pertenece a la isntancia pasa a ser un *'bound method', método enlazado* a dicha instancia:

```
>>> instancia.metodo_instancia
<bound method Clase.metodo_instancia of <__main__.Clase object at 0x7f1354c17278>>
```

El método de clase `metodo_clase` es un *método enlazado (bound method)* a la clase:

```
>>> Clase.metodo_clase
<bound method type.metodo_clase of <class '__main__.Clase'>>
>>> instancia.metodo_clase
<bound method type.metodo_clase of <class '__main__.Clase'>>
```

En ambos casos sirve como *factoría* (en nuestra implementación de la clase `Clase`) para crear nuevos objetos de tipo `Clase`:

```
>>> Clase.metodo_clase(3)
<__main__.Clase object at 0x7f1354c2bf60>
>>> instancia.metodo_clase(3)
<__main__.Clase object at 0x7f1352bfd828>
```

Por último, el `metodo_estatico` es la misma función, tanto en la clase como en la instancia:

```
>>> Clase.metodo_estatico
<function Clase.metodo_estatico at 0x7f1354bf8950>
>>> instancia.metodo_estatico
<function Clase.metodo_estatico at 0x7f1354bf8950>
```

Answer (score 6):

En Python, los métodos son por defecto métodos de instancia.

En Python hay tres tipos de métodos:

- *de instancia*: reciben la instancia del objeto como primer parámetro.
- *de clase*: reciben la clase como primer parámetro, equivalente a métodos marcados como `static` en otros lenguajes.
- *estáticos*: no reciben nada adicional como primer parámetro, equivalente a funciones libres que puedan estar en la misma unidad de traducción en otros lenguajes.