# ¿Para qué sirve @classmethod en python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Tengo la siguiente clase y me gustaría saber para que sirve el `@classmethod` arriba de cada método de la clase.

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, uid):
        return User.get_by_id(uid, parent = users_key())

    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, name):
        u = User.all().filter('name =', name).get()
        return u

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, pw, email = None):
        pw_hash = make_pw_hash(name, pw)
        return User(parent = users_key(),
                    name = name,
                    pw_hash = pw_hash,
                    email = email)

    @classmethod
    def login(cls, name, pw):
        u = cls.by_name(name)
        if u and valid_pw(name, pw, u.pw_hash):
            return u
```

Esta clase sirve para crear una entidad para el datastore de App Engine.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/936/c%c3%b3mo-son-los-m%c3%a9todos-de-una-clase-python-por-defecto

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@classmethod`, recibirá la clase como primer argumento, por si se necesita utilizar para algo. Se suele llamar `cls` por convención En este ejemplo todos los métodos lo tienen  `def by_name(cls, name):`. Para este propósito, C ++ tiene como función la sobrecarga, pero Python no, así que aquí es cuando se aplica `classmethod`. En resumen: Cuando se llama a este método, se pasa a la clase como primer argumento en lugar de la instancia de esa clase (como hacemos normalmente con métodos). Esto significa que puede utilizar la clase y sus propiedades dentro de ese método sin tener que instanciar la clase. Ejemplo:

```
 class Clase
    @classmethod
    def metodo2(cls, arg):
        pass

Clase.metodo2("argumento")
```

**Un ejemplo práctico:**

```
from enum import Enum


class Tamano(Enum):  # Una enumeracion es simplemente ponerle nombre a numeros
    normal = 1
    familiar = 2
    xl = 3


class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, precio, tamano, ingredientes):
        self.precio = precio
        self.tamano = tamano
        self.ingredientes = ingredientes

    @classmethod
    def napolitana(cls, tamano):
        precio_napolitana = 8990 * tamano
        ingredientes = ['Queso', 'Oregano', 'Tomate']
        # Instanciamos 'cls' que es la clase Pizza
        return cls(precio_napolitana, tamano, ingredientes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Puedo crear pizzas 'a mano':
    hawaiana = Pizza(9990, Tamano.normal, ['Tomate', 'Jamon', 'Pina'])

    # Creamos una pizza con nuestro metodo de clase
    napolitana = Pizza.napolitana(Tamano.familiar)
```

Answer (score 7):

Por completar la respuesta [@eduardo-munizaga](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4631), lo que observas en esta creación de *Entidad* es una especie de implementación del conocido patrón **Singleton**. En lugar de crear instancias, directamente está usando la clase, con sus atributos y sus métodos.

Pero sigue siendo una clase, por lo que se pueden derivar subclases que sobrecarguen atributos y métodos. Concretamente, `User` deriva de `db.Model`, donde irá a buscar los atributos y métodos que le falten. Por ejemplo, cuando en el método `register` retorna una instancia `User`:

```
@classmethod
def register(cls, name, pw, email = None):
    pw_hash = make_pw_hash(name, pw)
    return User(parent = users_key(),
                name = name,
                pw_hash = pw_hash,
                email = email)
```

Es lo que se conoce como *factoría* de instancias. Si lo analizas bien, tu clase `User` no tiene ningún método `__init__` para crear esta instancia, así que estaría usando el heredado a partir de `db.Model` que es donde se hace la magia.

Comment: En ningún ejemplo indicáis por qué no se utiliza "cls" dentro del metodo.

Comment: En la respuesta de @Eduardo_Munizaga sí que se está usando `cls`. Fíjate bien.

Comment: Si, pero en este ejemplo no se utiliza, por lo que no tiene ningún sentido  que sea @classmethod. Debería ser staticmethod como mucho

Comment: Das por asumido que nadie vaya a especilizar esta clase. Aunque yo no haga uso de la clase `cls`, es posible que una subclase sí.

Answer (score 0):

Es como los miembros de clase en Java. Es decir, que puedes acceder a los atributos y métodos de la clase sin necesidad de crear una instancia.